# HammerJS pull to refresh

Tags: javascript, hammer.js

I know very little about Javascript but need to use hammer.js in a project I'm working on.

Instead of replacing/refreshing the image im trying to use the pull to refresh scrit to refresh the page.

Ive tried adding

```
   location.reload();
```

to the script but to no avail, can anyone shed any light on this.

http://eightmedia.github.io/hammer.js/

This is the code im using

```
        /**
 * requestAnimationFrame and cancel polyfill
 */
(function() {
    var lastTime = 0;
    var vendors = ['ms', 'moz', 'webkit', 'o'];
    for(var x = 0; x < vendors.length && !window.requestAnimationFrame; ++x) {
        window.requestAnimationFrame = window[vendors[x]+'RequestAnimationFrame'];
        window.cancelAnimationFrame =
                window[vendors[x]+'CancelAnimationFrame'] || window[vendors[x]+'CancelRequestAnimationFrame'];
    }

    if (!window.requestAnimationFrame)
        window.requestAnimationFrame = function(callback, element) {
            var currTime = new Date().getTime();
            var timeToCall = Math.max(0, 16 - (currTime - lastTime));
            var id = window.setTimeout(function() { callback(currTime + timeToCall); },
                    timeToCall);
            lastTime = currTime + timeToCall;
            return id;
        };

    if (!window.cancelAnimationFrame)
        window.cancelAnimationFrame = function(id) {
            clearTimeout(id);
        };
}());


/**
 * pull to refresh
 * @type {*}
 */
var PullToRefresh = (function() {
    function Main(container, slidebox, slidebox_icon, handler) {
        var self = this;

        this.breakpoint = 80;

        this.container = container;
        this.slidebox = slidebox;
        this.slidebox_icon = slidebox_icon;
        this.handler = handler;

        this._slidedown_height = 0;
        this._anim = null;
        this._dragged_down = false;

        this.hammertime = Hammer(this.container)
            .on("touch dragdown release", function(ev) {
                self.handleHammer(ev);
            });
    };


    /**
     * Handle HammerJS callback
     * @param ev
     */
    Main.prototype.handleHammer = function(ev) {
        var self = this;

        switch(ev.type) {
            // reset element on start
            case 'touch':
                this.hide();
                break;

            // on release we check how far we dragged
            case 'release':
                if(!this._dragged_down) {
                    return;
                }

                // cancel animation
                cancelAnimationFrame(this._anim);

                // over the breakpoint, trigger the callback
                if(ev.gesture.deltaY >= this.breakpoint) {
                    container_el.className = 'pullrefresh-loading';
                    pullrefresh_icon_el.className = 'icon loading';

                    this.setHeight(60);
                    this.handler.call(this);
                }
                // just hide it
                else {
                    pullrefresh_el.className = 'slideup';
                    container_el.className = 'pullrefresh-slideup';

                    this.hide();
                }
                break;

            // when we dragdown
            case 'dragdown':
                this._dragged_down = true;

                // if we are not at the top move down
                var scrollY = window.scrollY;
                if(scrollY > 5) {
                    return;
                } else if(scrollY !== 0) {
                    window.scrollTo(0,0);
                }

                // no requestAnimationFrame instance is running, start one
                if(!this._anim) {
                    this.updateHeight();
                }

                // stop browser scrolling
                ev.gesture.preventDefault();

                // update slidedown height
                // it will be updated when requestAnimationFrame is called
                this._slidedown_height = ev.gesture.deltaY * 0.4;
                break;
        }
    };


    /**
     * when we set the height, we just change the container y
     * @param   {Number}    height
     */
    Main.prototype.setHeight = function(height) {
        if(Modernizr.csstransforms3d) {
            this.container.style.transform = 'translate3d(0,'+height+'px,0) ';
            this.container.style.oTransform = 'translate3d(0,'+height+'px,0)';
            this.container.style.msTransform = 'translate3d(0,'+height+'px,0)';
            this.container.style.mozTransform = 'translate3d(0,'+height+'px,0)';
            this.container.style.webkitTransform = 'translate3d(0,'+height+'px,0) scale3d(1,1,1)';
        }
        else if(Modernizr.csstransforms) {
            this.container.style.transform = 'translate(0,'+height+'px) ';
            this.container.style.oTransform = 'translate(0,'+height+'px)';
            this.container.style.msTransform = 'translate(0,'+height+'px)';
            this.container.style.mozTransform = 'translate(0,'+height+'px)';
            this.container.style.webkitTransform = 'translate(0,'+height+'px)';
        }
        else {
            this.container.style.top = height+"px";
        }
    };


    /**
     * hide the pullrefresh message and reset the vars
     */
    Main.prototype.hide = function() {
        container_el.className = '';
        this._slidedown_height = 0;
        this.setHeight(0);
        cancelAnimationFrame(this._anim);
        this._anim = null;
        this._dragged_down = false;
    };


    /**
     * hide the pullrefresh message and reset the vars
     */
    Main.prototype.slideUp = function() {
        var self = this;
        cancelAnimationFrame(this._anim);

        pullrefresh_el.className = 'slideup';
        container_el.className = 'pullrefresh-slideup';

        this.setHeight(0);

        setTimeout(function() {
            self.hide();
        }, 500);
    };


    /**
     * update the height of the slidedown message
     */
    Main.prototype.updateHeight = function() {
        var self = this;

        this.setHeight(this._slidedown_height);

        if(this._slidedown_height >= this.breakpoint){
            this.slidebox.className = 'breakpoint';
            this.slidebox_icon.className = 'icon arrow arrow-up';
        }
        else {
            this.slidebox.className = '';
            this.slidebox_icon.className = 'icon arrow';
        }

        this._anim = requestAnimationFrame(function() {
            self.updateHeight();
        });
    };

    return Main;
})();



function getEl(id) {
    return document.getElementById(id);
}

var container_el = getEl('container');
var pullrefresh_el = getEl('pullrefresh');
var pullrefresh_icon_el = getEl('pullrefresh-icon');
var image_el = getEl('random-image');

var refresh = new PullToRefresh(container_el, pullrefresh_el, pullrefresh_icon_el);

// update image onrefresh
refresh.handler = function() {
    var self = this;
    // a small timeout to demo the loading state
    setTimeout(function() {
        var preload = new Image();
        preload.onload = function() {
            image_el.src = this.src;
            self.slideUp();
        };
        preload.src = 'http://lorempixel.com/800/600/?'+ (new Date().getTime());
    }, 1000);
};
```

There is a Beer involved for anyone that can fix this :)

http://jsfiddle.net/zegermens/PDcr9/1/

Comment: Create an example on jsfiddle.net and you might recieve some help.

Comment: Please update the jsfiddle with your attempt to call location.reload()

Comment: Updated the jsfiddle, as i said i have no real understanding of JS apart from the basics so its more me just guessing roughly where it would go. I understand that the bottom part of the code is to refresh the image so i assumed i could add add a refresh page option there but still nothing.

Comment: Please post the link to the updated jsfiddle.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/zegermens/PDcr9/6/

Answer (score 0):

You're assigning the return value of the location.reload function to the src attribute of an Image element. I'm not sure if the function even has a return value, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location.reload

Try this:

```
// update image onrefresh
refresh.handler = function() {
    var self = this;
    // a small timeout to demo the loading state
    setTimeout(function() {
        window.location.reload();
    }, 1000);
};
```